# Aws-amplify integration with React Native Token - unauthorized

Tags: react-native, jwt, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have configured my React Native application to use a **Cognito user pool** that is used for user identity management and authentication using **AWS Amplify**. I am using Custom Authentication for user management. I am able to register, log in and perform other user management-related tasks. I also have an **API gateway** and a few **Lambda Functions** which I want to access through my React Native app. When I sign in, I receive a JWT Token which I want to send to the API gateway to access my Lambdas, but no matter what I do I get an **'unauthorized'** 403 or 401 message from my API Gateway.

**My question is:** How can I expose the API gateway/ Lambdas to the Cognito user pool users and Why the token generated by Cognito itself is unauthorized to access my api gateway.

**P.S.** - I used postman with the right Auth URL and settings, the postman token itself is authorized to access the API gateway and lambdas. (The user credentials are the same as I use with the React Native app)

I have spent a few days, any pointers in the right direction would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

NPN

[image]

```js
    Amplify Config:

    const awsmobile = {
      aws_project_region: 'us-XXXX-X',
      aws_cognito_region: 'us-XXXX-X',
      aws_user_pools_id: 'us-XXXX-XXXXXX',
      aws_user_pools_web_client_id: 'XXXXh1i5nXXXX',
      //aws_user_pools_web_client_secret: 'XXXXXoofuu0lXXXX',
      oauth: {
        domain: 'XXXXXXXX.us-XXXX-X.amazoncognito.com',
        scope: ["email", "openid", "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"]
      },
      aws_cognito_username_attributes: ['EMAIL'],
      aws_cognito_social_providers: ['GOOGLE'],
      aws_cognito_signup_attributes: ['XXXXX', 'XXXXX', 'EMAIL', 'XXXXXX'],
      aws_cognito_mfa_configuration: 'OFF',
      aws_cognito_mfa_types: [],
      aws_cognito_password_protection_settings: {
        passwordPolicyMinLength: 8,
        passwordPolicyCharacters: ['REQUIRES_LOWERCASE', 'REQUIRES_UPPERCASE', 'REQUIRES_NUMBERS', 'REQUIRES_SYMBOLS'],
      },
      aws_cognito_verification_mechanisms: ['EMAIL'],
    };

    export default awsmobile;
```

```js
  import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

  const login = async (username: string, password: string) => {
    const response = await Auth.signIn(username, password);
  console.log(response.data.signInUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken);
    return response;
  };
```

Comment: Show we the code of how you tried it.